# Regex to detect optional comment blocks followed by conditional blocks

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-re

I'm trying to write a script to detect and remove a #ifdef BUILD_FLAG ... #endif block from files with an optional comment block if it occurs right before it. So something like this will be removed

```
//this is s comment block
/**
*and a nested comment block
*/
//this is another comment block
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

I'm trying to do it with this code

```
block_comment_pattern = r'/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|\/\/.*?$|\/\/.*?(\n|$)'
conditional_block_pattern = rf'#ifn?def\s+{re.escape(build_flag)}[\s\S])*?)\s*#endif'
pattern = rf'({block_comment_pattern})?{conditional_block_pattern}'
MATCHER = regex.compile(pattern, re.M)
```

However, it's only able to detect a part of the comment block and the conditional block

```
//this is another comment block
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

When I tested the comment block pattern separately it was able to capture the whole comment block but not when combined with the conditional pattern. What is the better way/pattern to capture the example as mentioned above.

This is the demo of what I want to capture https://regex101.com/r/LLJV5i/1. In this demo, the whole comment block occurred right before the conditional block, both of them should be captured. (the comment block is optional, the conditional block is required)

Note:

- Block comments are optional and in C++ style ( where '//' be preceded
  on the same line with code and '*/' could be on a line by itself)
- There might be some spaces (indent) occurred before the block comments, and new line between the block comment and the conditional block (example 3)
- Those block comments in my demo are examples of what I want to capture
  Examples for the block comments that needs to be captured.

Example 1:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// this whole comment block and the conditional block below should be captured
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * @brief Some comment 
 *        
 *
 * @return 
 */
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

Example 2

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
// this whole comment block and the conditional block below should be captured
// --------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

Example 3

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * @comment: this whole block comment should be captured.
     * @{
     */

#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

Comment: The given regular expression doesn't match the contents of the #ifdef block at all. Are you sure you posted the right code?

Comment: @PeterSeliger thank you, I tried it with my examples on the demo link and it does not capture the example 3. It also over-captures some of the preceding comments above example 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace matches of the following regular expression (with `g` and `m` flags set) with empty strings:

```
(?:^ *(?:/\*\*[^/\n]*\r?\n(?:[^/\n]*\r?\n)*[^/\n]*\*/ *|//.*)\r?\n)+(?: *[\r?\n])*#ifdef BUILD_FLAG\r?\n[\s\S]*?^#endif\r?\n
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TNDFpm/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows (as well, hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function).

```
(?:                    # begin non-capture group
  ^                    # match beginning of line
  [ ]*                 # match >= 0 spaces
  (?:                  # begin non-capture group 
    /\*\*[^/\n]*\r?\n  # match '/**' followed by >= 0 chars other than '/' and
                       # newlines followed by the line terminator
    (?:                # begin a non-capture group
      [^/\n]*\r?\n     # match >= 0 chars other than '/' and newline then line term
    )                  # end capture group
    *                  # match the preceding non-capture group >= 0 times
    [^/\n]*            # match >= 0 chars other than '/' and newline
    \*/[ ]*            # match '*/' followed by >= 0 spaces
    |                  # or
    //.*               # match '//' followed by >= 0 chars other than line terms
  )                    # end non-capture group
  \r?\n                # match line terminator 
)                      # end non-capture group
+                      # match preceding non-capture group >= 1 times
(?:[ ]*[\r?\n])*       # match >= 0 lines containing zero or more spaces
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG\r?\n # match literal line
[\s\S]*                # match >= 0 any chars
?                      # match as few preceding tokens as possible
#endif\r?\n            # match literal at end of line
```

Note: I've represented spaces as character classes containing a space (`[ ]`) to make them visible.

Comment: Hi Cary, thank you for your answer and demo. It seems only capture the #ifdef...#endif part in the demo. DId I miss something?

Comment: It matches (but does not capture) the block you want to remove. You then need to convert it to an empty string in code. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear, I want to capture an optional comment block that's followed right by the conditional block and remove both of them (re.sub with ''). I'm still reading your note but I appreciate it

Comment: Does this work for you now?

Comment: Thank you so much Cary, I tested your pattern and there are some cases it does not work correctly, like this one https://regex101.com/r/fm0PEg/2 would there be any way that we could capture the whole comment block before the conditional block? Thank you

Comment: Before revising my answer I need to better understand the rules that apply to the comments. Are they [C or C++ comments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/comment)? Can a block comment terminate `'some text */'` (as opposed to `'*/'` being on a line by itself, as in your example)? Can `'//'` be preceded on the same line with code, as is permitted in C? You need to edit your question to clarify the rules concerning comments. Among other things please revise your example to illustrate all the ways comments may be written (including indentation).

Comment: Thanks Cary, they are more of C++ style comments, where '//' be preceded on the same line with code and '*/' could be on a line by itself. The 3 examples that I put on my demo are the 3 kinds of block comments that I want to capture, those could also be optional. I will edit the question to clarify some points. Thank you and I appreciate your time

Comment: I believe your link clarifies all points but one that I have. Within the comment blocks (between `'/*'` and `'*/'`), the first non-whitespace character in each line is `'*'`. Is that the case, considering there is no requirement for that in C and C++ style comments? Incidentally, you should put those examples in the body of your question since your question is incomplete without the link and links can be broken in future (however unlikely with regex101.com).

Comment: I think the main point for the /**...*/ block comments is it should capture anything in between the "/**" and "*/" and they could be spaces before them. I think these might not strictly the requirement for the style comments (correctly me if I'm wrong). Also I put those into my question body as you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you Cary, I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Please see if my last edit is OK. I've assumed lines containing `'/**'` have no forward slashes in the remainder of the line. That could be avoided but it's a pain. It would require use of the [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) technique. The main problem with the regex at your link is `[\s\S]*?`. Though non-greedy it was being a little too greedy in order to match the rest of the regex.

Comment: Thanks Cary, it works perfectly for my cases. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
BUILD_FLAG = "your_build_flag"
block_comment_pattern = r'/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|\/\/.*?$|\/\/.*?(\n|$)'
conditional_block_pattern = rf'(#ifdef {BUILD_FLAG}\n[\s\S]*?#endif)'
pattern = rf'({block_comment_pattern})?{conditional_block_pattern}'
MATCHER = regex.compile(pattern, flags=regex.MULTILINE | regex.DOTALL)
```

Comment: I tried it but it over captures other things in the files as well. Like, <block comment>...some code...<conditional blocks>. But I only want to captures the optional comment block if it occurs right before the conditional block